# Binding multiple selections of any type in MVC back to the model

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model, model-binding, html.dropdownlistfor

I have a model which contains a List and each Schedule has a List inside it, so in my view I have:

```
@foreach (Schedule sched in Model.Schedules)
{
    @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.SelectedCustomer, new SelectList(sched.Customers, "Id", "FirstName"), "Select A Customer", new { @class = "SelectedCustomer" })
}
```

So essentially this is outputting a dropdown/select tag for all the schedules, in the dropdown are a list of customers which I have found to the SelectedCustomer field. When I post this back to the (HttpPost) controller, none of my selections have been bound to my model. However if I was model binding a simple textbox, it works, but anything complex like a List of objects doesn't bind on postback, what is the recommended way in MVC to get back the selected values of all these dropdown boxes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I never found a way to bind to the model, but I found I could put an integer array of the SelectedCustomer like

```
int[] SelectedCustomer
```

and that bought back the selected form collection values for each dropdownlist.